# Using DataTransfer modifier with Custom Normals in Cycles

Tags: cycles-render-engine, normals

I am trying to use DataTransfer modifier in Cycles to improve toon shading on a character. I am using Face Corner Data - Custom Normals. I am getting strange shading with dark artifacts. Part of the problem seems to be that it marks every edge on my mesh as Sharp. If I unmark these, it marks them again next time I render.

I have used it in blender internal without problems. Is there some special settings combination you need to use this tool in Cycles, or does it just not work?